# Plotting points on a map, the json objects retrieved from a database; using WebGL shader code

Tags: postgresql, json, jquery

I am using an OSM dataset using which I am plotting those points on a map (google maps API). I am plotting these points using webgl shader code (see:  http://psousa.net/demos/webgl/)

The above link by itself is an extension of the Google maps WebGL example :  http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvaslayer/examples/hello_webgl.html. The difference between the example I quoted and mine is, I have imported the OSM dataset into a postgres database. I am fetching the result (the points that i need to plot) as json objects. After I get the json objects, I am trying to plot these using the webgl shadercode as in the example link above.

The problem is, I am getting the json points (when I do a console.log) but my webgl code does not plot these points. I do not know where I am going wrong.

Here is my code for retrieving the points from the postgres database using jquery, as json objects:

//data.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

     $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "/database.php", 
                    data: { 
                           format: "json"
                               },            
                   success: function(data)
                                     {
                      points = data;
                      console.log(data); 
                                      }
                   });
  });
```

The rest are same as in the example link.

Every other function such as `resize()`, `translateMatrix()`, `scaleMatrix()`, `init()`, `loadData()`, `update()` are the same. The only difference is that, while the example plots random points across the map, I am plotting the points I retrieved from my postgres database as json objects. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit : This is the postgres query I used:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326)) FROM planet_osm_line WHERE highway IS NOT NULL AND ref = 'US 101' AND ST_Intersects(way, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope((-122.302571660907), (37.5601802504715), (-122.436330806712), (37.8074531813721), 94326), 900913));
```

and the output is in this format:

```
"LINESTRING(-122.436063557915 37.7998944536137,-122.436172613391 37.7998804703684,-122.437602282165 37.7996967004673,-122.437703791792 37.7996837109204)"
```

(I am retrieving points within a bounding box)